# Javascript - Class Variables vs Class Methods - what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Was just wondering in Javascript, what's the difference between having two formats for class methods like so:

```
handleClick = (ev) => {
   ...
}

handleClick() {
 ...
}
```

Is there any difference at all aside from hoisting? Memory footprint, or scope, or performance?

This question is not about howto pass functions along as props in React. This specifically if I am planing to use my functions inside the class itself like this.calculateSomething();

Comment: I disagree. The question above is about passing functions as props to react components. Imagine I don't even use react, just vanilla JS, I am still using a class and I want to know if there is any difference when I am using functions inside the class.

Comment: The only difference is that class variables can be lambda functions which means they don't have context. Class methods do have context.

Comment: @Alexus read the answers carefully, they address every use-case (props, class property handlers, etc).

Answer (score -3):

As far as V8 is concerned there is no benefits related to performance.Just the different syntax